# Rails - use join only if a condition is true

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How do I use joins only if a certain condition is true?
For example, I have this query:

```
@courses = Course.find(:all,
    :order=> 'courses.name asc',
    :include => [:units],
    :joins => :course_sub_responsibles,
    :group => 'courses.name',
    :conditions => conditions)
```

But I need to join the course_sub_responsibles table only in a certain condition.

Comment: The arguments are a hash-only add the join to the hash if your condition is met.

Comment: Write your condition to a hash and add the join condition when met, after that call Course.find(hash)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **ActiveRecord.find** method takes a Hash as last argument (which is written without curly braces, but it is a hash indeed), which means you can do that:

```
options = { :order=> 'courses.name asc',
:include => [:units],
:group => 'courses.name',
:conditions => conditions }

options[:join] = :course_sub_responsibles if YOUR CONDITION GOES HERE

@courses = Course.find(:all, options)
```

Comment: Thanks. Only issue is that it should be :joins with 's'.

Comment: @saverio, what the hell are you talking about? how is that related to the solution i offered and why is that considered a downvote? do you have a better solution? if not, then you should not downvote other people's right answers.

Comment: Someone deleted my previous comment. Anyway I edited your answer to better suit the actual reason you can pass a hash as last argument (which is completely unrelated to having `*args`!!!). Once edited, ok, the response is right (given that probably the OP is using Rails 2). Downvote removed.

Answer (score 2):

You should use ARel-powered methods:

```
@courses = Course.scoped  # Course.all in rails 4
@courses = @courses.order("courses.name asc").includes(:units)
@courses = @courses.joins(:course_sub_responsibles) if YOUR_CONDITION
@courses = @courses.group("courses.name")
@courses = @courses.where(conditions)
@courses
```

This will only execute the query when the variable is iterated, but the query will be built by pieces, so you can add/remove pieces when you need to.

In Rails4 it will be even cleaner (note the bangs, which mean "modify the receiver" as usual):

```
@courses = Course.all
@courses.order!("courses.name asc")
@courses.includes!(:units)
@courses.joins!(:course_sub_responsibles) if YOUR_CONDITION
@courses.group!("courses.name")
@courses.where!(conditions)
@courses
```

Comment: I get an error: No Method Error. Will this method work with rails 1.8.7?

Comment: 1.8.7 is the ruby version (and you should really use 1.9.3). What's the rails version?