# how to use joins only if condition is met

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to make a **joins** query but only if a condition is met.

In previous version of rails when find was used, I would be able to use:

```
options = { :order=> 'courses.name asc',
:include => [:units],
:group => 'courses.name',
:conditions => conditions }

options[:join] = :course_sub_responsibles if YOUR CONDITION GOES HERE

@courses = Course.find(:all, options)
```

But in current version, how can I do that?

See here:
[Rails - use join only if a condition is true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12882515/rails-use-join-only-if-a-condition-is-true)

But the second answer will not work for me, because I can not build the query piece by piece. Doing so will cause the first query to fetch a huge amount of data.

Comment: Im not 100% sure but it doesnt seem possible, you will probably have to put the joins in a condition

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you can do something like:

```rb
query = Course.where(<your conditions>).order(<your order>)
query = query.joins(<your joins>) if YOUR CONDITION GOES HERE
@courses = query
```

Rails won't query the database until you use something like to_a / each / pluck.

To test this in the console you can do something like (borrowing from @3limin4t0r's comment):

```rb
foo = Course.all; nil
```

At this point no SQL should have been run. If you then do `foo` on the console you'll see it run the query - the console will print out the result and this will trigger rails to grab the data for it.

Comment: I checked it in a console. The query is being executed on the first line...

Comment: @NoamB. That's a bit misleading as (I'm pretty sure) the console triggers the query. I'll see if I can add some code to illustrate that.

Comment: Yep, the console uses `#inspect` to display the result. Which in turn [queries the database](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/75ac626c4e21129d8296d4206a1960563cc3d4aa/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation.rb#L731-L738). However `#inspect` is not used when the code is placed in a script and the query is only executed when the data is needed (`#to_a`, `#load`, `#map`, etc.) The example in your second code block can be simplified to `foo = Course.all; nil` (all on a single line) which returns `nil`, thus not triggering the `#inspect` method of the query.

Comment: You can also use the modifier version of joins i.e. `joins!` to avoid the `query = query#...` portion. This is what `joins` does however it spawns first (essentially a `dup` for an ActiveRecord query chain)

Answer (score 1):

you can create a `scope` that will check the `condition` before `joins`

```rb
class Course
 scope :joins_if, -> (table, cond) {
  joins(table) if cond
 } 
end
```

then

`Course.where...joins_if(:course_sub_responsibles, YOUR CONDITION GOES HERE)`